# XPath How to get the count of a parent node with multiple filters including child node

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Here is example XML:

```
  <Pnode PFilter="1">
    <Child1>
        <Child2 Filter="1"></Child2>
        <Child2></Child2>
    </Child1>
    <Child1>
        <Child2 ></Child2>
        <Child2></Child2>
    </Child1>
    <Child1>
        <Child2 Filter="1"></Child2>
        <Child2></Child2>
    </Child1>
  </Pnode>
  <Pnode>
    <Child1>
        <Child2 Filter="1"></Child2>
        <Child2></Child2>
    </Child1>
    <Child1>
        <Child2 ></Child2>
        <Child2></Child2>
    </Child1>
    <Child1>
        <Child2 Filter="1"></Child2>
        <Child2></Child2>
    </Child1>
  </Pnode>
  <Pnode>
    <Child1>
        <Child2 Filter="1"></Child2>
        <Child2></Child2>
    </Child1>
    <Child1>
        <Child2 ></Child2>
        <Child2></Child2>
    </Child1>
    <Child1>
        <Child2 Filter="1"></Child2>
        <Child2></Child2>
    </Child1>
  </Pnode>
  <Pnode>
    <Child1>
        <Child2></Child2>
        <Child2></Child2>
    </Child1>
    <Child1>
        <Child2 ></Child2>
        <Child2></Child2>
    </Child1>
    <Child1>
        <Child2></Child2>
        <Child2></Child2>
    </Child1>
  </Pnode>
</Doc1>
```

I am trying to get the count of all PNodes that dont have PFilter="1" and have at least 1 child2 filter=1.

In the example above, the result should be 2.

`expession="count(//Doc1/Pnode[not (@PFilter='1') and (Child1/Child2[@Filter='1'])])"`

seems like it should work.
Am I missing some syntax or something?

I also thought maybe
`expession="count(//Doc1/Pnode[not (@PFilter='1') and (count(Child1/Child2[@Filter='1'])>1)])"`

Is there a way to get the count of a parent with these type of filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work. Please have a try:

`expression="count(//Pnode[not (@PFilter='1')][Child1/Child2[@Filter='1']])"`

Or

`expression="count(//Doc1/Pnode[not (@PFilter='1')][Child1/Child2[@Filter='1']])"`

Comment: It keeps returning 1 for both.

Comment: I'm using chrome console, which returns 2. How did you get 1, is that escaped properly if using with java?

Comment: Oh my goodness, i found my mistake. This does work! Thank you!